# Segues without a navigation controller look strange. Should I just use a Navigation Controller and hide the bar?

Tags: swift

I am currently designing an app that does not have a Navigation Controller. Whenever I make a segue to another view, it presents it as a strange drop-down tab instead of showing it normally. For example, this is what the view looks like after the segue.[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyAK8.png). I just want a normal looking push segue. Is there an easy fix or is it a concept that I am missing altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Push to any `UIViewController` it is mandatory to have `UINavigationController` which manages the navigation hierarchy. If you bind a segue without `UINavigationController` it will not push that controller and it will be presented only. iOS manages this automatically.

Even if you forcefully try to push without `UINavigationController` through code, your app will get crashed.

In your case it will work like this:

- You have two `UIViewController` **A** & **B**
- You want to push from **A** to **B**
- Bind Controller **A** in `UINavigationController`
- Add **Push Segue** from **A** to **B**